# How to split a java text block by lines?

Tags: java, java-text-blocks

Let's say we have the following java text block :

```
         String textblock = """
                 A : 111
                 B : 111
                 C : 1111
                 """;
```

I would like to split it by lines to get the following result :

```
         String [] splitedTextBlock = splitTextBlockSomeHow(textblock); 
         // expected result : {"A : 111", "B : 222", "C : 333"}
```

Comment: `String.split(text, "\n")`. Then again by ":" to get your key/value pairs.

Comment: @Jorn you probably meant `text.split("\n")` (or even `text.split("\n", -1)`)

Comment: Thanks you both, i found also that i could use `text.split(System.lineSeparator())` to make it more generic

Comment: @user16320675 Could be! Since I switched to Kotlin, I never remember what in the Java stdlib is static and what isn't.

Comment: alternatives: `text.lines().toArray()` or `text.lines().toList()`

Comment: You need to be a little careful of indentation with text blocks, so you might be safer with something like `String [] splitTextBlock = textblock.lines().map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);`

Comment: @karl-knechtel, unfortunately, it doesn't answer how to split by line separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static String[] splitTextBlock(String textblock) {
   return textblock.trim().split(System.lineSeparator());
}

...

String textblock = """
        A : 111
        B : 111
        C : 1111
        """;
        
String[] splitedTextBlock = splitTextBlock(textblock);
Arrays.stream(splitedTextBlock).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `System.lineSeparator()` won't work if you receive *different* line separators than what you have on the current system. For example, running the code on Linux but reading or getting some text which uses Windows line endings. Or vice versa.

Comment: @vlaz thank you for this point, I am using it in context of unit test

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

```
String textblock = """
        A : 111
        B : 111
        C : 1111
        """;

String[] splitedTextBlock = textblock.split("\\R");

for (String line : splitedTextBlock) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

- the `split("\\R")` method is used to split the text block by lines
- the `\\R` regular expression pattern matches any line break, including different line break sequences like `\n` or `\r\n`